# Difference between Cron and Crontab?

Tags: unix, cron

I am not able to understand the answer for this question: "What's the difference between `cron` and `crontab`." Are they both schedulers with one executing the files once and the other executing the files on a regular interval OR does `cron` schedule a job and `crontab` stores them in a table or file for execution?

[**Wiki page**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for `Cron` mentions :

> **Cron** is driven by a crontab (cron table) file, a configuration file
>   that specifies shell commands to run periodically on a given schedule.

But [**wiki.dreamhost**](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215088608-Crontab-overview) for `crontab` mentiones :

> The crontab command, found in Unix and Unix-like operating systems, is
>   used to schedule commands to be executed periodically. It reads a
>   series of commands from standard input and collects them into a file
>   known as a "crontab" which is later read and whose instructions are
>   carried out.

Specifically, When I schedule a job to be repeated : (*Quoting from wiki*)

```
1 0 * * *  printf > /var/log/apache/error_log
```

or executing a job only once

```
at -f myScripts/call_show_fn.sh 1:55 2014-10-14
```

Am I doing a `cron` function in both the commands which is pushed in `crontab` OR is the first one a `crontab` and the second a `cron` function?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**cron** is the general name for the service that runs scheduled actions. **crond** is the name of the daemon that runs in the background and reads **crontab** files. A **crontab** is a file containing jobs in the format

```
minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week  command
```

crontabs are normally stored by the system in `/var/spool/<username>/crontab`. These files are not meant to be edited directly. You can use the **`crontab`** command to invoke a text editor (what you have defined for the EDITOR env variable) to modify a crontab file.

There are various implementations of **cron**. Commonly there will be per-user crontab files (accessed with the command `crontab -e`) as well as system crontabs in `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.hourly`, etc.

In your first example you are scheduling a job via a crontab. In your second example you're using the `at` command to queue a job for later execution.

Comment: so..in my example commands....both are `cron` which are stored in `crontab` file???

Comment: Your first example would go in a crontab file. You'd add it via **crontab -e**. The second example uses the **at** command and would not be in a crontab.

Comment: so second example is neither `cron` not `crontab` because of **at**??

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can use **at** with no **cron** daemon running. **at** is typically used for one-time actions while **cron** is for recurring tasks.

Comment: Excellent teardown.  The most concise and lucid description I've ever run across.

Comment: After editing with `crontab -e`, my user's crontab file was located at `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/<username>`. This must have changed in the last few years. Also, there's a default editor selector (nano vs vim vs etc) for my crontab. This setting is located at `/home/<username>/.selected_editor` (or `~/.selected_editor') and changeable via the `select-editor` command