# Cascade deletion of database record to deletion of associated image file

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, innodb, cascading-deletes

I recently discovered the wonders of foreign keys and deletion cascading with InnoDB and I love it. It helps me easily delete intricate data structures without worrying about leaving junk behind.

I'm currently storing images for a products database (like you would have on a web-shop) in the following manner:

My `products` table is what you would expect, it has an `id` primary column.
My `product_images` table has a `product_id` column with a foreign key to the `products.id` column, and an `image` column of type varchar storing the image file name.

The file names are created by computing the SHA1 hash of the image, then storing in a folder named after the first 2 characters of the hash:
`61/6153A6FA0E4880D9B8D0BE4720F78E895265D0A9.jpg`. In the database, only `6153A6FA0E4880D9B8D0BE4720F78E895265D0A9.jpg` is stored.

Now, if I were to delete a product from the database, the cascading DELETE rule would delete the record in the `product_images` table, but would leave the file on my server.

Is there a way to automate the deletion of the image file whenever a record in the `product_images` table is deleted, be it specifically or by cascading? Maybe link some kind of trigger or routine to the deletion operation?

Comment: I don't think feature like this exists in MySQL, but would love to hear ways to solve this problem

Comment: This is yet another reason why I don't use `CASCADE` (or `FOREIGN KEYs`, for that matter), but rather do all the work in the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no native functionality built into mysql to perform this. If there were, there would be no end in sight to turning it into feature-creep and a full blown high-level programming language. Bloat-ware, getting away from its core competency.

People have used UDF libraries compiled in C that integrate into mysql either as object files or compiled into the server source. See the sections [Adding New Functions to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-functions.html), and [UDF Repository for MySQL](http://www.mysqludf.org/). It become like a science fair project, where after you get it to work once, you probably won't want to roll it out to a fleet of other servers.

So what are you alternatives? The safe bets are always to write to another table (outside of your cascade delete hierarchy) the directory/filename combo. And have another mini-system do the housecleaning for you. For instance, twice a day, in Java or c# or python (any language). Those environments have db libraries, and robust file operations. It will be tremendously easier that way anyway.

I do these type of things to extend the functionality of mysql-related activities that are primarily file based or forbidden calls inside of stored procedures and [events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32508935).

Comment: Thanks for an in-depth answer. I was hoping there would be some kind of analogue to the TRIGGERs that would allow me to execute a script or interact with the file system. Too bad :) As you said, I guess I could create a trigger that would log the deletion in a separate table, then poll that table periodically to know which files I should delete.

Comment: The use of UDF's are sketchy. Then how do I easily deploy. You will find much more power and happiness I believe with your code nestled elsewhere. Sorry it was not what you hoped for (at the moment).

Comment: Check out [cron](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21789148) which is wildly popular for running a task, whatever you put in an appropriate string with a schedule via `crontab`.

Answer (score 0):

You would use below code for deleting the specific file.

**Note:** your file name ($filName) would come from your query.

```
$filName;
$dirName = substr($filName, 0, 2);

chown($filName,465);
unlink("../".dirName."/" . $filName);
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my request. I know how to delete a file on a server, but I want to know how to automatically perform this deletion if a row is deleted from my table (hence the word cascading). I want to somehow link a script to the mysql deleting operation.

Answer (score 0):

when inserting images to DB change it's name to be linked with it's product 
or it's category .
when deleting category search for imaged that have names involve cat id then unlink it

this code can help

```
        foreach(glob(IMG_PATH.'cat_'.$_POST['id'].'*.*') as $file)
        {
            if(is_file($file))
            {
                @unlink($file);
            }


    }
```